# Compare two json values for equality

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

(Note that this is using the Preview [`JSON`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data) feature in BigQuery.)

Is there a simple way to compare two json values to see if they're equal, ignoring key-ordering, recursively, for example:

```
{a: 1, b:2}    ===      {b:2, a:1}
```

As an example:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT JSON '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' as a, JSON '{"b": 2, "a": 1}' as b
) SELECT a,b, a=b?? FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JS UDF (this is bot recursive, but you can modify the js code to make the comparison recursive )

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_compare(a STRING, b STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js
  OPTIONS (
    )
AS r"""
    obj1=JSON.parse(a);
    obj2=JSON.parse(b);

    keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
    keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

    //return true when the two json has same length and all the properties has same value key by key
    return keys1.length === keys2.length && Object.keys(obj1).every(key=>obj1[key]==obj2[key]);
""";

SELECT json_compare('{"a":1,"b":2}', '{"b":2,"a":1}');
```

Or adding json sort function:

```
 CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_sort(a STRING)
          RETURNS STRING
          LANGUAGE js
          OPTIONS (
          )
          AS r"""
          obj1=JSON.parse(a);
        
          const sortKeys = (o) =>
          Object (o) !== o 
          ? o
          : Object .keys (o) .sort () .reduce ((a, k) => ({...a, [k]: sortKeys (o [k])}), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT a,b, TO_JSON_STRING(a) = TO_JSON_STRING(b) 
FROM tbl
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Is there any guarantee, documented or otherwise, that the "sort" order of the TO_JSON_STRING output is stable?

Comment: if you do `select * from your_table` do you think you are guaranteed to get columns in the output in the stable order? I think, the same answer is applicable to question in your above comment :o)

Comment: Is that speaking to the representation of JSON in BQ, or the implementation of TO_JSON_STRING? I'm obviously not familiar with either, so don't understand the analogy. I do observe that BQ lacks even containing checks like @> and <@ from Postgres.

Comment: I asked GCP support about this, and they replied:

"In theory we don't guarantee that 2 equivalent JSON values will produce the same result [from TO_JSON_STRING], but in practice they will and there is no reason that this will change."

Further, they mentioned a comparison function is on the roadmap, estimated for late 2023.

Comment: Didn't work for me, they come unordered

Comment: @Brachi same for me, in 2023 -- `select to_json_string(struct('david' as name, 10 as age)) = to_json_string(struct(10 as age, 'david' as name))` gives me `false`.

Comment: Hi @David542
select to_json_string(to_json(struct('david' as name, 10 as age))) = to_json_string(to_json(struct(10 as age, 'david' as name)))