# Compare two structs in BigQuery recursively ignoring key order

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a complex struct, perhaps with ten levels of nesting and repeated fields. Is there a built-in way to compare these two objects to see if they are the same minus the sorting of keys? This may be related to: [Compare two json values for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047991/compare-two-json-values-for-equality). An example might be:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "type": "Powdered Sugar" , "id": "5007"},
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ],
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        }
}
```

Versus:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "type": "None", "id": "5001"  },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: will help if you can provide actual reusable data sample :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047991/compare-two-json-values-for-equality), we learnt that JSON type allows such a comparison, then it is just a matter of how to use JSON type as a proxy to compare the 2 structs

```sql
with data as (
  select struct<a string, b struct<x string, y string>>('a', ('x', 'y')) col1,
         struct<b struct<y string, x string>, a string>(('y', 'x'), 'a') col2,
) select col1,
         col2,
         TO_JSON_STRING(PARSE_JSON(TO_JSON_STRING(col1))) = TO_JSON_STRING(PARSE_JSON(TO_JSON_STRING(col2)))
 from data;
```